# Pythonでファイル名と同じフォルダ名に保存がしたい

Tags: python, windows

Pythonでファイル名と同じフォルダ名に格納したい

PyPDF2でPDFを分割をしました。分割処理までは出来たのですが、その先の分割したファイルを指定のフォルダに格納するやり方が分かりません。 やりたいこととして、テストフォルダ内の「１」「２「３」へのフォルダ名に
分割したファイル名の１.pdf ,2.pdf,3.pdfのファイルをそれぞれフォルダに格納させたいです。

フォルダは先に新規で作成した状態です。

１.pdf → １のフォルダ
２.pdf → ２のフォルダ
３.pdf→ ３のフォルダ

開発環境はWindowsで

Pythonか、Windowsコマンドのバッチなど処理で可能でしょうか？
もし可能ならご教示願います。

```
import PyPDF2
 
# プログラム2｜フォルダ内のPDFを全て取得
curdir = os.getcwd()
files = list(pathlib.Path(curdir).glob('*.pdf'))
  
# プログラム3｜フォルダ内の全てのPDFを処理
for file in files:

  merger = PyPDF2.PdfFileMerger()
  merger.append('test1.pdf', pages=(1, 9))
  merger.write('test4.pdf')
  merger.close()
```

Comment: やりたい事の説明と提示されたソースコードが微妙に合っていないようです。まあオブジェクトやメソッドが分割では無く結合/追加を意識させるものだからかもしれません。分割と言うよりも1-9ページを抽出する処理が1回だけ行われて、それで1個の新しいファイルだけを書いているようですが、それで良いのでしょうか？ また`for`ループでループ毎に扱われる`file`の変数は処理には出ていなくて、`test1.pdf`,`test4.pdf`という固定のファイル名が使われていることの間は、どんな関係がありますか？ コメントで良いので、ここでこんな単位で分割を行いたいとか、そのファイル名は何を基に決めたいとか、ここで何かをしなければならないはずだとか、書き込んでみてください。

Comment: フォルダが作成済であるならばPDFファイルの保存時に保存したいフォルダの中に保存すれば良さそうです。そうはできない理由がありそうですがそれは何でしょうか？質問文とコードからはその辺りがよく分かりませんでした。

Comment: まあ単にピンポイントで質問のフォルダ名のパス名を得たいならば、[os.path.splitext(path)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.10/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) が使えるでしょう。そのパスが存在しているかは[os.path.exists(path)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.10/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists)で、それがフォルダかどうかは[os.path.isdir(path)](https://docs.python.org/ja/3.10/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir)で分るでしょう。

Comment: 済みません、ちょっと紛らわしかったですね。「コメントで良いので」というのはこのサイト上の記事のコメント機能では無く、提示されたソースコード上に何かここで処理を入れたいが分からないのでコメントとして記入する、という形で書いてください。

Answer (score 0):

フォルダ名とファイル名を`/`または`\`のセパレータで区切って指定することで、フォルダ名とファイル名を指定できます。
PDFのページ番号はPyPDF2の[`numPages`](https://nanonets.com/blog/pypdf2-library-working-with-pdf-files-in-python/#extracting-document-details-with-pypdf2)プロパティで取得できるので、例えば1ページ目は`.\1\1.pdf`など、ページ番号ごとにループして保存したいならば、下記のようなコードで実現できます

```
pdf = PdfFileReader(src)
for i in range(pdf.numPages):
    # 分割データ作成
    dest = PdfFileWriter()
    dest.addPage(pdf.getPage(i))
    with open(f"./{i+1}/{i+1}.pdf", "wb") as f:
        dest.write(f)
```

なおフォルダ内のpdfをglobで取得していますので、ファイル名を一律で`1.pdf`のように設定すると既存の同名ファイルを上書きしてしまいます。

要件の推測を多分に含みますが、分割後のファイル名のプレフィックスに既存ファイル名を設定する(例えば `TEAMS_content_health.pdf` の1ページ目は `TEAMS_content_health_1.pdf` になる)場合は、下記のサンプルコードのようなコーティングで対応できます。

ご質問のコードではPDFの結合をしており分割処理が見当たらない点や、`for`文の中でページ番号を記載していない点から、ご質問の意図が汲み取りにくく感じました。
この回答が的外れな場合は、コメントの指摘事項などを質問文に追記してみてください。

**サンプルコード**

```
import urllib.request
import os
from pathlib import Path
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader, PdfFileWriter

# サンプルPDFをダウンロードして取得する(※ダウンロードできない場合は代替ファイルをご用意ください)
urls = ["https://x54cwjdqkdu7-so-docs.netlify.app/pdf/teams/b_b/general_information/TEAMS_content_health.pdf",
        "https://x54cwjdqkdu7-so-docs.netlify.app/pdf/teams/b_b/getting_started/TEAMS_ask_a_question.pdf"]
for url in urls:
    src = url.split("/")[-1]
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, src)

# フォルダ内のPDFをループしながら分割する
for src in Path().glob('*.pdf'):
    # サンプルPDFのページを分割して保存する
    pdf = PdfFileReader(src)
    for i in range(pdf.numPages):
        # 分割データ作成
        dest = PdfFileWriter()
        dest.addPage(pdf.getPage(i))
        # 分割後のファイル名(例えば TEAMS_content_health.pdf の1ページ目は TEAMS_content_health_1.pdf になる)
        name = f"{Path(src).stem}_{i+1}.pdf" 
        # ページ番号に該当する数字フォルダがなければ作成
        os.makedirs(str(i+1), exist_ok=True)
        # ファイル出力(数字フォルダ内に分割後のファイル名でファイルを保存する)
        with open(f"./{i+1}/{name}.pdf", "wb") as f:
            dest.write(f)
```

**実行結果**

```
> tree /F test
フォルダー パスの一覧:  ボリューム Windows 
ボリューム シリアル番号は FFFF-FFFF です
{フルパス}\TEST
├─1
│      TEAMS_ask_a_question_1.pdf.pdf
│      TEAMS_content_health_1.pdf.pdf
│
├─2
│      TEAMS_ask_a_question_2.pdf.pdf
│      TEAMS_content_health_2.pdf.pdf
│
├─3
│      TEAMS_content_health_3.pdf.pdf
│
└─4
        TEAMS_content_health_4.pdf.pdf
```

Comment: `src`は `PurePath`サブクラスなので, `folder = src.parent/ str(page)`, `fname = folder/ f'{src.stem}_{page}{src.suffix}'` とか可能です。`folder.mkdir()`も使えます